# Why did this happen after deploying my ASP.Net Dynamic Data Web App to a test server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, templates, insert

I deployed the web application that I've been developing to our test server for the first time today, and for some odd reason the "insert" hyperlink on the Insert.aspx page template is not functioning.  It's not throwing an error, and I can insert into the tables in question on the remotely hosted SQL Server DB like so:

```
protected void btInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BedType bt = new BedType();
    bt.Value = "Twin";
    bt.MaxSpace = 1;

    using (OEContext context = new OEContext())
    {
        context.BedTypes.Add(bt);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But when attempting to insert using the default Insert.aspx template, the "insert" hyperlink just doesn't function ("cancel" works fine though!)

Google-fu has failed me all afternoon.  I have no ideas and am totally stumped...

Comment: Does it show an error? Does it return without doing anything? Is there any logging or error handling?

Comment: It shows no error..  As far as I can tell it's not even posting back.  There's no error handling except for the default from EF, because it's a completely unmodified DynamicData/PageTemplate..

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas for me?  I'm still completely stumped..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much banging my head on the desk, I've figured out the answer to this rather strange issue and wanted to post it in case anyone else comes across the same problem.

When I installed the "AJAX Toolkit" using NuGet, my app stopped compiling because it wasn't finding the "MsAjaxBundle" Web Resource that the script manager was looking for:

```
<asp:ScriptReference name="MsAjaxBundle" />
```

This code was added to my Site.Master file when I added the reference to the ajax control toolkit.  Because it was looking for that bundle, and it didn't exist, I did a bit of googling and found the web resource and registered it with my script manager in my Global.asax file:

```
ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("MsAjaxBundle", new ScriptResourceDefinition
{
    Path = "~/bundles/MsAjaxJs", 
    CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5/6/MsAjaxBundle.js", 
    LoadSuccessExpression = "window.Sys", 
    CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true
});
```

And it compiled and ran!  But, for some reason, the app was suppressing a "WebForm_PostBackOptions not defined" error.  Once I caught that and began digging, I was led back to my MsAjaxBundle and ultimately realized that it was the culprit.  A bit more googling and came across this page:

http://stephenblog.wpengine.com/archive/2012/09/20/september-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit

which pointed to some changes in the ScriptManager:

1) We need to replace the asp:ScriptManager with the ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager

2) We need to remove the MsAjaxBundle bundle from the ScriptReferences

3) We need to remove the Assembly=”System.Web” attributes from the ScriptReferences

And my problem was solved.  If anyone that has more knowledge and experience than me could explain why this happened in the comments, then feel free!  I'm just happy that I'm through this one, as it was particularly frustrating for me :P